# Filtering folder names with Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I have written a very simple script to grab a list of folders like below. My question is :  I want to export an output like my desired output.

Does anyone here have any information that would help me out?

My script :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\GENERAL" -Recurse -Directory -Depth 5 |
    Select-Object FullName |
    Export-Csv c:\tmp\out.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

My output :

```
"FullName"
"D:\GENERAL\IT"
"D:\GENERAL\SOFTWARE"
```

My desired output :

```
"FullName"
"D:\GENERAL"
"D:\GENERAL\IT"
"D:\GENERAL\SOFTWARE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the root folder in the output, add a (*non-recursive*) call to `Get-Item`. Wrap both commands in a scriptblock `{…}`, so you are able to process their output uniformly. The scriptblock is called using the call operator `&`. It can be treated like a single command, which enables us to pipe its output to other commands.

```bash
$path = "D:\GENERAL"
& {
    Get-Item -Path $path
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory -Depth 5
} |
    Select-Object FullName |
    Export-Csv c:\tmp\out.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

---

An alternative way that avoids the `$path` variable:

```bash
"D:\GENERAL" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Item -Path $_
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse -Directory -Depth 5
} |
    Select-Object FullName |
    Export-Csv c:\tmp\out.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Here we are piping the path as input to `ForEach-Object` which becomes available as `$_`, the current pipeline object, within `ForEach-Object`'s *process* script block.